# How much does the Starter Set cleric's Cure Wounds spell heal?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Cure Wounds spells says it heals 1d8 + spell ability modifier. For a lvl 1 cleric, that's +3 wisdom.

However, the pregenerated cleric character sheet from the Starter Set says he has the **Disciple of Life** ability, which adds +2 +spell level to the healing done.

Does this mean cure wounds heals for 1d8 +3 +2 +spell level?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

> **Disciple of Life**
>
> Also starting at 1st level, your healing spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell's level.

So if you cast cure wounds at 1st level you will regain 1d8 + Wis Mod (+3) + 2 + Spell Level (1) = 1d8 + 6

This makes Life Clerics very potent healers.

*Note: that if you cast a spell at a higher level the spell level will also increase, e.g. casting with a 2nd level slot it will heal 2d8+7 and with a 3rd level slot 3d8+8.*